# Trouble calling Macro by variant

Tags: excel, vba

A friend helped me with this macro but Im having trouble calling it. Basically i want to delete all columns not specified in the array.

```vb
Sub KeepColumns(columnsToKeep As Variant)

'Declare variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim col As Variant

'Set the worksheet you want to work with
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("testflik")

'Loop through each column in the first row and delete it if it is not in the list of columns to keep
For Each col In ws.Rows(1).Columns
If Not IsError(Application.Match(col.Value, columnsToKeep, 0)) Then
'Do nothing, this column should be kept
Else
'Delete the column
col.EntireColumn.Delete
End If
Next col

End Sub
```

To use the macro, call it and pass in an array of the columns you want to keep
For example:

```
'Declare the columns you want to keep
columnsToKeep = Array("short_description", "name", "name_specifics", "category.name", "product.configurable_parent_sku", "sku", "supplier_sku")

'Call the macro
KeepColumns (columnsToKeep)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Im having trouble" is no good starting point to be able to help you. How do you call the function, what exactly is happening - instead of what you expect. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: As with all delete loops, you will need to start from the last column first as otherwise the indexing goes out of alignment, so use something like `For i = ws.Rows(1).Columns.Count To 1 Step -1` to loop and you could check for a match to delete with something like `If Not Application.Intersect(ws.Cells(i, 1), columnsToKeep) Is Nothing` if you passed a range, but for values you can probably keep what you have (although there is likely a better solution).

Comment: Furthermore you should search the most right column and confine the loop to a range containing only the actual headers, otherwise match and deletion will iterate all columns; there are numerous posts telling you how to get the last column.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```vb
Sub KeepColumns(columnsToKeep As Variant)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, col As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("testflik")
    For col = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count) To 1 Step -1 '## loop backwards
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Cells(1, col).Value, columnsToKeep, 0)) Then
            ws.Columns(col).Delete
        End If
    Next col
End Sub
```

Note you should not use parentheses when calling this, so

```
 KeepColumns columnsToKeep
```

not

```
KeepColumns (columnsToKeep)
```

You only use parentheses in a call if you're using the `Call` statement (which is deprecated I think) or if you want to capture the return value from a method.  [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-statement#:%7E:text=You%20are%20not%20required%20to%20use%20the%20Call%20keyword%20when%20calling%20a%20procedure.%20However%2C%20if%20you%20use%20the%20Call%20keyword%20to%20call%20a%20procedure%20that%20requires%20arguments%2C%20argumentlist%20must%20be%20enclosed%20in%20parentheses.%20If%20you%20omit%20the%20Call%20keyword%2C%20you%20also%20must%20omit%20the%20parentheses%20around%20argumentlist)

Also you might want to consider what happens when there's a balnk/empty column header - should that be deleted, or not?